# plotting a boolean array as a translucent overlay over a graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the `True` parts of a boolean array as translucent boxes over another plot.

This sketch illustrates what I envision. I know I could do that with Asymptote, but I (among other reasons) need to verify that the data I work with is concise. I can supply example code of a graph and a boolean array if that helps - I don't have an idea yet how to realize the overlays, though. Asymptote might be the best option for producing plots for later publication, though.

[image: sketch of a graph with boolean overlay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overlay boxes, you can use [Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) from matplotlib. I used the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/errorbars_and_boxes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbars-and-boxes-py) to create them as a [patchcollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection).

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# boolean and plot data
n_points = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 2.5 * np.pi, n_points)
my_truth = np.zeros(n_points)
# true regions must be surrounded by false, pad by 1 false if needed
my_truth[20:40] = 1
my_truth[60:70] = 1


def get_truth_intervals(logical_data):
    """ extract 'true' regions embedded in 'false' regions """
    truth_spikes = np.diff(logical_data)
    truth_starts = np.argwhere(truth_spikes == 1)
    truth_ends = np.argwhere(truth_spikes == -1)
    return truth_starts, truth_ends


with plt.xkcd():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

    # draw boxes defined by true sections and plot height
    y_start, y_end = ax.get_ylim()
    boxes = [Rectangle((x[x_start[0]], y_start),
                       x[x_end[0]] - x[x_start[0]],
                       y_end - y_start)
             for x_start, x_end in zip(*get_truth_intervals(my_truth))]
    # implement all rectangles as a single collection
    pc = PatchCollection(boxes, facecolor="red", alpha=0.2,
                         edgecolor="red")
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    ax.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I LOVE your plot and font style!!!

Comment: Perfect! That is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: could you please tell me what to loook for so i can learn about the loop syntax:  for... in construct AFTER the body of the loop, and the "with" indented as it is?

Comment: @Andreas read about **list comprehension** and [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: yes, as mozway mentioned, this is a list comprehension, see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp. It's basically a short way to construct a list, instead of having to initialize an empty list first and the fill it with .append(). The `with` is context manager to get the "shaky" xkcd (https://xkcd.com/) plot style, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html for further details on that or for a general context manager explanation https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html